# Installing cuDF & cuML into Colab with Rapids.ai version 0.11+

Tags: python, conda, google-colaboratory, rapids

I'm trying to install Rapids library with cuDF and cuML to Colab session,
and executing code accroding to this example:
from 
[Install RAPIDS library on Googe Colab notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53813125/install-rapids-library-on-googe-colab-notebook/59561868)

````
!wget -nc https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rapidsai/notebooks-contrib/890b04ed8687da6e3a100c81f449ff6f7b559956/utils/rapids-colab.sh
!bash rapids-colab.sh

import sys, os

dist_package_index = sys.path.index("/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages")
sys.path = sys.path[:dist_package_index] + ["/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"] + sys.path[dist_package_index:]```
sys.path
if os.path.exists('update_pyarrow.py'): ## This file only exists if you're using RAPIDS version 0.11 or higher
  exec(open("update_pyarrow.py").read(), globals())
````

during the installation process i got this error:

```
  - cudf=0.11

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai-nightly/label/xgboost/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai-nightly/label/xgboost/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai-nightly/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai-nightly/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I have tried to install cuDF and cuML separately with

```
conda install -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge \
    -c defaults cudf=0.12 python=3.6 cudatoolkit=10.0
```

but still receiving the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-10-a95ca25217db> in <module>()
----> 1 import cudf
      2 import io, requests
      3 
      4 # download CSV file from GitHub
      5 url="https://github.com/plotly/datasets/raw/master/tips.csv"

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cudf'
```

how to solve this error?

Comment: Is your jupyter using the right python kernel, i.e. the anaconda/miniconda one?

Comment: i use this code to install Conda: 
```!wget -c https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local```

Comment: i only able sucessfully install version rapids / cudf 0.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE (12/21/2020): to jump right into a GPU powered RAPIDS notebook online you can  **use [BlazingSQL](https://app.blazingsql.com) (RAPIDS 0.15+)** or continue using Colabratory (RAPIDS 0.14 only)

UPDATE (2/19/2020): Circling back to this question, Colab is working @try.  Have fun!

Let us know if you have any other questions.  If you need to update your personal Colab notebooks, please use this script to install RAPIDS:

```
# Install RAPIDS
!git clone https://github.com/rapidsai/rapidsai-csp-utils.git
!bash rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/rapids-colab.sh

import sys, os

dist_package_index = sys.path.index('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages')
sys.path = sys.path[:dist_package_index] + ['/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages'] + sys.path[dist_package_index:]
sys.path
exec(open('rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/update_modules.py').read(), globals())
```

Previous response:

> we are in the middle or transitioning our Colab scripts to a new repo.
> We should have all our notebooks updated soon and try to help others
> migrate as well.  Like within 24 hours, if not by EOD today PST.

Comment: Seems that this is asking for `pyarrow` and `pynvml` first, so I installed it first doing `!conda install --yes --prefix /usr/local pyarrow pynvml`. Maybe would be good to include this on the script.

Comment: Following tis directions, I got `pyarrow` installed without adding it - but `cudf` fails to load with a missing shared lib:   Could not load shared object file: libllvmlite.so

Comment: I somehow fixed by copying it `!cp /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/llvmlite/binding/libllvmlite.so .` but then got stuck in a numba imort error:  `AttributeError: module 'numba' has no attribute 'core'` (which conda says it is installed correctly and up-to-date) - this is with py3.6

Comment: Same with me - i am also getting this error  `AttributeError: module 'numba' has no attribute 'core'`. Tried upgrading numba - making changes in the _init_.py within numba folder but issue doesnt seem to resolve

Comment: @epifanio - I went to the __init__.py within numba folder in the python - site_packages folder and converted all the codes that were doing `import numba.core.types` to `from numba.core import types` and additionally also disabled the check - #_ensure_llvm() ....post this i was able to import cudf and also read a csv file using the same. The python init file is in **/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/**

Comment: igorkf @vivek epifanio Right now, Google Colab supports Python 3.6 and RAPIDS .14.  For RAPIDS 0.15+ (we're on 0.17 at time of this comment), you can try app.blazingsql.com.  They have instances that are RAPIDS ready and require no additional installs. I will update my answer.  I will also look into seeing what fixes can be done to the rapids-colab install script.

Comment: Thank you @TaureanDyerNV - i have tried BlazingSQL  and found it useful given the fact that the environment is already setup

Answer (score 2):

After running the code of @TaureanDyerNV RAPIDS suggested making the following code change. It takes 15 minutes to run.

```
!git clone https://github.com/rapidsai/rapidsai-csp-utils.git
!bash rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/rapids-colab.sh 0.19

import sys, os, shutil

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM'] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/lib64/libnvvm.so'
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE'] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/libdevice/'
os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'] = '/usr/local'
for so in ['cudf', 'rmm', 'nccl', 'cuml', 'cugraph', 'xgboost', 'cuspatial']:
    fn = 'lib'+so+'.so'
    source_fn = '/usr/local/lib/'+fn
    dest_fn = '/usr/lib/'+fn
    if os.path.exists(source_fn):
        print(f'Copying {source_fn} to {dest_fn}')
        shutil.copyfile(source_fn, dest_fn)
if not os.path.exists('/usr/lib64'):
    os.makedirs('/usr/lib64')
for so_file in os.listdir('/usr/local/lib'):
    if 'libstdc' in so_file:
        shutil.copyfile('/usr/local/lib/'+so_file, '/usr/lib64/'+so_file)
        shutil.copyfile('/usr/local/lib/'+so_file, '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/'+so_file)
```

Comment: Given Google Colab limits on GPU usage, how comfortable it is to work with RAPIDS in Colab notebooks? Have you hit any inconveniences?