# Not able to install cudf, cupy and cuml into colab with rapids.ai version 21.08

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, cupy, cudf

I am trying to install cudf and cuml on google colab pro following this tutorial: [rapids_cudf.ipynb - Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ritchieng/deep-learning-wizard/blob/master/docs/machine_learning/gpu/rapids_cudf.ipynb)

But after running the following block of code:

```
# intall miniconda
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local

# install RAPIDS packages
!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local -c conda-forge \
  -c rapidsai-nightly/label/cuda10.0 -c nvidia/label/cuda10.0 \
  cudf cuml

# set environment vars
import sys, os, shutil
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM'] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/lib64/libnvvm.so'
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE'] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/libdevice/'

# copy .so files to current working dir
for fn in ['libcudf.so', 'librmm.so']:
  shutil.copy('/usr/local/lib/'+fn, os.getcwd())
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f6f0b40601c8> in <module>()
     15 # copy .so files to current working dir
     16 for fn in ['libcudf.so', 'librmm.so']:
---> 17   shutil.copy('/usr/local/lib/'+fn, os.getcwd())

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    118         os.symlink(os.readlink(src), dst)
    119     else:
--> 120         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
    121             with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    122                 copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libcudf.so'
```

I have the following GPU: b'Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB' on colab pro.

And after running the code block given above, python version is: `Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.`

These are the other specifications:

```
# Check Ubuntu Version
!lsb_release -a
```

Output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

```
# Check CUDA/cuDNN Version
!nvcc -V && which nvcc
```

Output:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Oct_12_20:09:46_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.105
Build cuda_11.1.TC455_06.29190527_0
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc
```

I have already tried to follow this tutorial of [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60188071/installing-cudf-cuml-into-colab-with-rapids-ai-version-0-11), but was not able to install cudf or cuml.

Answer (score 2):

This file is using outdated installation code and incompatible CUDA options.  I'll be sure to ask the maintainer to update it.  Please use the newest code, found in the `rapids-colab template` here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TAAi_szMfWqRfHVfjGSqnGVLr_ztzUM9#scrollTo=G_2dancFhf70.